# Confused about the purpose of React-Redux package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm able to directly access the store's state inside my react components using "store.getState()" without react-redux and dispatch actions on the store. Why would I wanna use react-redux?

Comment: Is the [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) front page selling points not sufficient enough? It's designed to work with the React component lifecycle.

Comment: with store.getState() you cannot read a piece of state from the store. Consider you have a deeply nested component which only want the username from the store and the component should re-render only when the username from the store changes . with store.getState() your reading the entire store meaning whenever any value in the store changes now your component will re-render which is unnecessary . But react-redux gives you optimized selectors which you can use to read the store data efficiently and avoid unwanted re-renders . This is just one case . But react-redux gives many such advantages.

Comment: @Shyam I'm afraid that explanation is at least partly incorrect. Calling `store.getState()` has zero cost. In fact, `useSelector` actually calls `store.getState()` internally! What matters is A) actually subscribing to the store to know _when_ to check the state for updates, and B) running comparisons to see if the data needed by _this_ component has actually changed. See [The History and Implementation of React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/) for details on how this works.

Comment: @markerikson actually I wanted to tag you in the post so that you can answer the user . But I am not sure whether SO has a tagging feature . Thanks for the detailed explanation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You should *not* be directly importing the store into your component files](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#only-one-redux-store-per-app), for multiple reasons:

- This can cause circular import dependency issues, which will break your app
- You will have to hand-write a ton of complex store subscription and data diffing logic yourself, and you will almost definitely get that wrong
- Your components will be locked to that one store instance and not easily testable
- React-Redux implements all that store subscription and diffing logic for you, so that you don't have to
- React-Redux has had tens of thousands of hours of development time put into it to make sure that the behavior is correct and optimized
- All actual React + Redux apps use the React-Redux library to do the work

Please see [The History and Implementation of React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/) and [ReactNext 2019: A Deep Dive into React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2019/06/presentation-react-redux-deep-dive/) for more details on how React-Redux works and what it does for you, and [Redux Fundamentals: UI and React](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react) for our tutorial on how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

of-course you can, but `react-redux` is a pkg for gluing react into the redux. this is the official way to doing this as stated in react-redux website as well. also it is optimized as well to update and rerender your component only when your component related data is been updated. so imagine if you use `store.getState(somestate)` your component will updated when ener your store update.

So Overall it is the official way for connecting your react components to your redux store. Also, with the rise of hooks in the react community, it will provide you with some helper hooks to make your react developer experience much easier.